# Can't get a Console to VMs

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, xen

I've followed this otherwise [excellent tutorial](http://howtoforge.com/ubuntu-8.04-server-install-xen-from-ubuntu-repositories) on getting Xen working with Ubuntu but am not able to get a console into my virtual machine (domU). I've got the `extra = '2 console=xvc0'` line in my /etc/xen/**hostname_here**.cfg file like they say, but am not able to get a console on it.

If I statically assign an IP to the VM I can SSH to it, but for now I need to be able to use DHCP to give it an address (and since that's what I'm trying to debug, there's the problem). I know I've got a free DHCP address (although I'm getting more at the moment), so I don't think that's the problem. I've looked on Google and the Xen forums to no avail as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had followed a different tutorial on setting up my xen on ubuntu before 8.04 but now upgraded to 8.04. I used the extra line in my cfg as folows:

```
extra = ' TERM=xterm xencons=tty console=tty1'
```

It allows me to "xm console hostname" from dom0. I think this was from a problem with the xen setup in the version prior to 8.04 (I'm not sure which version that was). I'm not sure if the same change is necessary in 8.04 as I'm an upgrade and didn't change any of my domU configs after the upgrade.